# How to get application path in dependency resolvers?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have local maven repository in `repo` subdirectory. Need to point to that directory in resolver path, but examples below doesn't work. How to get `application path` in this config ?

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  resolvers += "my1" at "file://${Play.application().path()}/repo"
  resolvers += "my2" at "file://${application.path}/repo"
  resolvers += "my3" at "file://${play.application.path}/repo"
)
```

In controller class using `Play.application().path()` point to path than i need to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Build.scala are project classes and settings not available because it builds the play project. But you can use some SBT magic:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
  resolvers <+= baseDirectory { base => 
    "local maven repo in project" at ("file://" + base.getAbsolutePath + "/repo")
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank You very much. On Windows i had to add one slash after _file://_  (`"my" at "file:///"+base.getAbsolutePath+"/repo"`)